# AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'presence_of_element_located'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Simply the code is:

```
timeout = 3
element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'content'))
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
```

But whatever I select from that page, xpath or id, I always get this error **AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'presence_of_element_located'** and I couldn't find a single solution on the web unfortunately. Any ideas? Thanks.

And I am switching to frame prior to that code I am not sure if that has an effect. Because I have to but it wasn't causing an error when I use enough time.sleep(), I am trying to save time by using WebDriverWait but it won't work.

```
frame = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tokenpageiframe"]')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
```

Edit: Didn't mention but everything needed was already imported.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from telnetlib import EC
```

Comment: have you imported it from this?
`from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC`

Comment: Thanks @ble but that and every other needed imports are imported.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like import issue as mentioned by @ble :

These would be the **imports** :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

also as you have mentioned "And I am switching to frame prior to that code I am not sure if that has an effect. "

if the ID `content` is in the same iframe then there is no change required but if it is outside the `tokenpageiframe` iframe then first you need to switch to default content :

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

and try that out.

the below code is also equivalent  :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'content')))
```

Comment: Everything needed was imported, my bad for not mentioning. And thanks I will try.

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't have enough information to answer, but, looking at your code, maybe one of your variables used to find have a "b" before your text. example: b'content'. This traceback says that. To work with this variable you should decode it back to utf-8 example:

```
element_present.decode('utf-8')
```

Then you try again.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
```